# Syntax error in Java class definition

Tags: java

Could anyone please explain to me what is wrong here?

Thanks.

```
public class test {

    int num1 = 1, num2 = 2;

    num1=num1+num2;

}
```

It errors on "num1=num1+num2;" saying "Syntax error on token ";", , expected"

Why?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put arbitrary statements, such as `num1=num1+num2;` at class level. Statements must always be inside methods, constructors or (static or non-static) initializer blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment isn't in a method or static initialiser block. Briefly, *when do you expect it to execute* ?

Answer (score 0):

You're adding outside of a method, do so in the main and make num1/2 static, or do so in another method, not in blank space.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given your code a method, so your summation is not in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

put this `num1=num1+num2;` inside a method or an initializaton block, you cant put assignment statements outside methods/constructors/initialization blocks.

```
    {
    num1=num1+num2;
    } 

or 

  public void m1() {
    num1=num1+num2;
     }
```